# SELECT DISTINCT for email but also get another column

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

Trying to get only unique emails but also show the shipping name.

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(email) As email FROM tbl_order");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo " ".$row['shipping_name'].",".$row['email']." <br />";
}
```

But it does not show the shipping name, any help would be great, thank you so much.

Comment: do thry have the same `email` but different `shipping_name`?

Comment: If there are several shipping names associated with the same email, which one would you expect to see?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT(email) As email, shipping_name FROM tbl_order

Comment: You should use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements instead of mysql_ functions, theyve been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(email) As email,shipping_name FROM tbl_order" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
("SELECT DISTINCT(email) AS email, shipping_name FROM tbl_order")
```

or

```
("SELECT email, shipping_name FROM tbl_order GROUP BY email")
```

Answer (score 0):

To give you exact code:

```
$resultArray = array();
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(email) as email,shipping_name FROM tbl_order");
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
//echo " ".$row['shipping_name'].",".$row['email']." <br />";
$resultArray[$i]['shipping_name'] = $row['shipping_name'];
$resultArray[$i]['email'] = $row['email'];
$i++;
}
var_dump($resultArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(email) As email,shipping_name FROM tbl_order");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo " ".$row['shipping_name'].",".$row['email']." <br />";
}
```